# Creating a character string using a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to find out whether, in my `listdf` (a list of 3 dataframes), one or more row names are equal to `NA`. I do this by creating a string named `test` here, such as :

```
test <- as.character()
for(i in 1:length(listdf)) {test[[i]] <- listdf[[i]]$rowname}
str(test)
 chr [1:3] NA NA NA
```

However, I am trying to do the same thing but without the need to create `test`. I'm trying to use the `print` function for this, but I don't know how to keep them as a string, as `test` does.

```
for(i in 1:length(listdf)) {print(listdf[[i]]$rowname)}
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

In the end, I want to make an `if else` loop, which when one of my `listdf`'s has a `rowname` equal to `NA`, tell me `TRUE`, otherwise if there is no `NA`, tell me `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget to precise, `df` is a list of 3 dataframes. I renamed it `listdf`

Comment: why would you need to convert the output of the test function to character, whereas keeping it as logical would be much more useful and flexible?

Comment: print() will rarely give us useful output, it is intended for iteractive use only.

Comment: Thank you @DarrenTsai it works perfectly by adding `any` to your suggestion!

Comment: Indeed @GuedesBF , I was looking to keep it as a logical character, but I don't really know how to do that, hence my question. I was also wondering how to avoid having to create a string and keep it simple. The `sapply` function seems to be very useful for this, I'm not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```r
df.list <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(rowname = c(1, 2, 3)),
  df2 = data.frame(rowname = c(1, NA, 3)),
  df3 = data.frame(rowname = c(1, 2, 3))
)
```

You can use `sapply` + `anyNA` to loop over each dataframe in the list and check if there are any `NA` in the `rowname` column.

```r
sapply(df.list, \(x) anyNA(x$rowname))

#   df1   df2   df3 
# FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```